# Could someone ELI5 returning object array values from this code example?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello All^^  I apologize for the simplicity of this question (and my JS comprehension), beforehand.  Could someone explain why the following code returns the key value in the object array?  I would expect that *array-name[n]* would return the key, rather than the value in the array.  I thought that *array-name[n][1]* would produce the value (name of the shape in this example) in this function ( 
 i.e., if *4* is entered, "square" would be returned). 
For the background, this was an edabit challenge that I solved.  However, that was not entirely on purpose(I was initially trying to use a loop to perform the same function for about a half hour, to no avail).  To digress, I would simply like to understand this more thoroughly, if possible.  I appreciate your time.

```
    const polygons = {
     1 :  "circle" ,
     2 :  "semi-circle",
     3 :  "triangle",
     4 :  "square",
     5 :  "pentagon",
     6 :  "hexagon",
     7 :  "heptagon",
     8 :  "octagon",
     9 :  "nonagon",
     10 : "decagon"
};
return polygons[n];
}
```

Comment: What is n in your example? a number between 1 and 10?

Comment: Because that's how objects (`polygons` isn't an array here) work. If you want the keys use `let keys = Object.keys(polygons);`

Comment: Yes, n is always a number between 1 and 10^^  Sry for leaving that bit out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polygon is an object. It is not an array hence you are seeing this behavior. See code below for better explanation.

```
// This is object. Doing polygons[4] will give you square
const polygons = {
  1 :  "circle" ,
  2 :  "semi-circle",
  3 :  "triangle",
  4 :  "square",
  5 :  "pentagon",
  6 :  "hexagon",
  7 :  "heptagon",
  8 :  "octagon",
  9 :  "nonagon",
  10 : "decagon"
};

function getFromObject(n) {
  return polygons[n];
}

// This is array. Doing polygons[4] will give you pentagon (because array index start from 0)
const polygons = [
  "circle" ,
  "semi-circle",
  "triangle",
  "square",
  "pentagon",
  "hexagon",
  "heptagon",
  "octagon",
  "nonagon",
  "decagon"
];

function getFromArray(n) {
  return polygons[n];
}
```

If you need keys from your object, you could do `Object.keys(polygons)`. This return you array of keys. I am not sure what your usecase is but this how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I thought that this was called an "object array", rather than a regular array.  However, my coding verbiage understanding is poor.  So `1 : "circle"` is simply one value of the object?  They are still key and values, are they not?  If I am mistaken (which is likely the case), then what would `1` and `"circle"` be called, respectively?  Please let me know.

Comment: `1: "circle"` is a key/value pair in the object `polygons`. `1` is the key which corresponds to the value `"circle"`. Together, they create a key/value pair, which is unique; you cannot have 2 identical keys in an object. [MDN Object Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is a great resource to learn more!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  That makes sense and confirms my understanding of key/values.  I suppose, what was confusing to me was why object[n] grabs only the value.  I thought that a one bracketed number argument would translate to the key position (rather than the value position). Anyway, thanks again^^  Really appreciate it.